# How to avoid error "Incorrect usage/placement of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"?

Tags: mysql, sql-calc-found-rows

We have in our application two queries, the first very long which takes 30 seconds, and then another to get the number of rows before the LIMIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS res.*,...GROUP BY...HAVING...ORDER BY fqa_value LIMIT 0,10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count
```

We can optimize the speed from 30 seconds down to 1 second if we take out the "ORDER BY fqa_value".

So I put everything in a subselect and then sort it:

```
select * from (
    SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS res.*,...GROUP BY...HAVING...LIMIT 0,10;
) as temptable order by fqa_value;
```

However this gives me the error: "Incorrect usage/placement of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS".

If I take the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS out, it works:

```
select * from (
    SELECT DISTINCT res.*,...GROUP BY...HAVING...ORDER BY fqa_value LIMIT 0,10
) as temptable order by fqa_value;
```

But then I don't have the original number of rows that was selected before GROUP BY  and HAVING.

**How can I both (a) count the original rows, and (b) have a fast query? I'm looking preferably for a pure MySQL solution so we don't have to change the code if necessary.**

Answer (score 1):

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` should go before `distinct`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT res.*,...GROUP BY...HAVING...ORDER BY fqa_value LIMIT 0,10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html says the opposite, DISTINCT before SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS